# Hibernate Statistics statement count - incorrect

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, unit-testing

I have a bidirectional one to many relationship as follows. And in my test, I insert one parent and 3 children entities. Then I count the number of prepared statements. Hibernate tells me it's 6 but in the log I see only 4 insert statements logged. Why is this happening?

```
public class Order {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addLine(Line line) {
        lines.add(line);
        line.setOrder(this);
    }
}

public class Line {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Order order;
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
    public void test() {
        Statistics stat = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getSessionFactory().getStatistics();
        Line line1 = Line.builder().lineNbr("1").build();
        Line line2 = Line.builder().lineNbr("2").build();
        Line line3 = Line.builder().lineNbr("3").build();
        Order order = Order.builder().orderNbr("1").lines(new ArrayList<>()).build();
        order.addLine(line1);
        order.addLine(line2);
        order.addLine(line3);

        repo.saveAndFlush(order);
        assertEquals(4, stat.getEntityInsertCount());
        assertEquals(4, stat.getPrepareStatementCount()); // this fails. Hibernate says it's 6
    }
```

This is what I see in the log:

```
Hibernate: insert into orders (order_nbr, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into line (line_nbr, order_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into line (line_nbr, order_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into line (line_nbr, order_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)

927500 nanoseconds spent preparing 6 JDBC statements;
2732200 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC statements;
2118000 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC batches; -------- what is this?
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `Line` insert counts as normal statement, the following two count as batch inserts i.e. they reuse the same statement or use JDBC batching. Not sure if they are still counted as prepared statements as well, but I think so.